# ColladaLoader horizontal vector

Tags: three.js, blender

I use [blender](https://www.blender.org/) and `three.js` to read the `.dae` file respectively, the `blender` shows parallel to the x and z axes, but `three.js` shows that it is tilted 90 degrees to the y axis.

[Example file](https://gitlab.com/po_developer/dae-file-example/-/tree/main/1b03f03d-88a2-4c12-9c75-82539a48c081)(1b03f03d-88a2-4c12-9c75-82539a48c081)

**blender:**
[image]

**three.js:**

```
let loaderDae = new ColladaLoader();
loaderDae.load('assets/1b03f03d-88a2-4c12-9c75-82539a48c081/untitled.dae', (dae: any) => {
      this.model = dae.scene.children[0];
      this.model.position.multiplyScalar(0);
      this.scene.add(this.model);
    });
```

[image]
[image]

I don't know if it's a problem with the vector in the original file, or with `three.js` reading it, should I modify the original file or adjust the vector through `three.js`?

How can I flip the model if it is through `three.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this.model = dae.scene.children[0];

Since you are doing this, you skip a transformation of the root object that performs the up axis conversion. So just do this:

```js
this.model = dae.scene;
```

In general, you should really consider the usage of Collada (as well as OBJ and FBX) since the more modern glTF is better in so many ways. At least when exporting a glTF asset from Blender, it will automatically care about proper up axis conversion.

Comment: The model of my example is public data, this data base does not provide gltf format download. I tried to use `blender` to convert the file to `.glft` output, but I can't read it successfully on `three.js`, is there any tutorial on how to convert the file format correctly?

Comment: No sorry. But the [three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/) or the Blender community might be good places if you need help to export glTF from Blender so it is correctly rendered in `three.js`.